# userXXXXXX showing instead of my full name

Tags: support, display-names

Why is user100380 showing up in my posts instead of my full name? This is happening on all the stack exchange sites to which I am posting.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Profile Display Name edit]

When you go to your profile and click "edit", you'll see the above textboxes. I assume you have filled in your full name in "Real Name", but this field is private. If you want to have your full name as display name, put it in the "Display Name" field.

Answer (score 6):

Your account exists for two days. It seems to me you created a new account instead of using your existing one. Maybe you used other credentials? Another OpenID provider?

If you want to, you can [merge this account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist) with your previous one.

If this is your first account, you can [edit your current account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) in order to change your username.

Comment: The edit your current account link you posted is broken. Could you please fix it?

Comment: Done that. @user100380